# Write a service over Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, python, maven, service, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to write a service to connect with Google Cloud Dataflow (GCD). My idea is:

1. A service receive requests (containing SQL rows, JSON, Plain Text and etc.).
2. The service sends the data to one (or more) pipeline(s) on GCD (according to the request type).
3. The used pipeline executes a transform on the data.
4. The GCD pipeline writes on Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and on another Google Cloud service (e.g., BigQuery).

In my research, I found Google's API (Python) to communicate with GCD. That part is OK, just some need some reading. The problem is: **how do I deploy the pipeline(s)?**

I did the **Getting Started** tutorial: created a maven project, compiled and executed the **WordCount** codes and used it to write my own logic. However every time I need to run a job, I have to call `mvn [compile] exec:java foo1.foo2...fooN.BarClass` from my terminal. The code is then uploaded to the Cloud and executed.

How can I "let the code there", deployed as a service, and just connect my own service to it? Do I need to upload the Java code every time I use it? Deploy as a JAR file somewhere and call it somehow? Can I re-run a finished job? Or the pipeline only executes as a slave?

The documentation is not clear about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help me understand -- when you say "run my own service", it sounds like you're looking for a way to decouple and buffer incoming data from a variety of sources.  Is this something that you could use Cloud Pub/Sub for?  Specifically, all requests in (1) are sent to Pub/Sub, and then your streaming pipeline ingests them, covering (2-4).

Comment: Here where I work, we use micro-services for the entire platform. We have one named **Cerebro** (Brain in Portuguese) that nowadays only tracks the app screen (clicks, scrolls and all sort of screen event). The idea is to extend this to start filling a Data Lake (and later create/extend Data Analysis tools)... [will continue]

Comment: ...[continuation]

So, I need to have a service, even if it initially just pass the data to GCD, because our other services cannot be dependent of a platform (we may change from Google Cloud to another in the future).

I am thinking in use Pub/Sub, but what is not clear to me is if I have to deploy (somehow) the logic used by the Pipeline. So far the code is entirely uploaded every time I execute the "maven-exec" command. Then, what I think is the logical assumption is to deploy a JAR file somewhere in GCD and have a endpoint to connect another service (my own, Pub/Sub or another).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) as a any-to-Dataflow ingestion mechanism for a [streaming Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params), which would then be "always on", and capable of publishing to another service or another Cloud Pub/Sub topic.

This provides a layer of decoupling for your service, since you can swap out Dataflow for another processing layer at any time, since all your senders and receivers will only need to understand the Pub/Sub or other transport API.

Comment: Hum... but, where is my Dataflow logic? The Pub/Sub connects a publisher (in this case, my micro-service) to a subscriber (in this case, a Pipeline of Cloud Dataflow). However, the Dataflow must be a server to receive a HTTP request.

The great question is: where is my Dataflow logic? The documentation is very poor in this. Is like they were not ready for a real-world application yet.

Comment: PS: as a streaming Dataflow, the input is unbounded. To me it would make more sense to execute a batch job (as I was doing), creating an "slave instance" of the Dataflow Pipeline when my service requests.

After reading Pub/Sub docs, the problem has no solution yet. The pub/sub need a server as publisher and other server as subscriber (aka, the Dataflow must be "encapsulated"). That doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: The Dataflow logic is in the pipeline that you deploy, which _pulls_ from Pub/Sub.  Hence, it does not need to be an HTTP server.

Comment: My answer got hammered so I'll just leave it here. Being locked in won't be that big of a deal since the the pipeline from the SDK can run on supported runners other than the google cloud dataflow service.

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I have a north now. Will try and in a few days I update you (and, I hope, close the topic).